# php code executes else statement after completing query

Tags: php, android, mysql

My android studio console is supposed to receive "success" if "insert" query is successful. This is only successful if "hub_code" is new otherwise it won't insert. However if i register with a different hub_code the query registers the user however it executes the "codexist" echo. also, the create table query is irrelevant in this question. my android code si also irrelevant as i only seek to know why the console only receives "codexist". Below is my php code.

```
<?php 

     $dbconn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
     mysqli_select_db($dbconn,"mydatabase"); 

    $username = $_POST["un"];
    $password = $_POST["pw"];
    $f_name = $_POST["fn"];
    $l_name = $_POST["ln"];
    $hub_code = $_POST["hc"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];




     if (!empty(($username)&&($password)&&($f_name)&&($l_name)&&($hub_code))) 
     {  

         $query = "SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE hub_code = '".$hub_code."'";
         $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query); 
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)  
         {        
              $query1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(username, password, f_name, l_name, hub_code, type) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$f_name', '$l_name', '$hub_code','LECTURER')";
              $sql1=mysqli_query($dbconn,$query1); 
              $query2 = "CREATE TABLE $hub_code (
                              ID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                              monday int(1) NOT NULL,
                              tuesday int(1) NOT NULL,
                              wednesday int(1) NOT NULL,
                              thursday int(1) NOT NULL,
                              friday int(1) NOT NULL,
                              saturday int(1) NOT NULL,
                              sunday int(1) NOT NULL,
                              weekcounter int(2) NOT NULL,
                              assdate DATE NOT NULL )";
               $result2 = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query2);
                if(trim($sql1) != "")
                {
                    echo "Success";

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Failure";
                }

         }
         else 
         {
            echo "codexit";
         }
    }



     else
     { 
        echo  "One or both of the fields are empty ";

     }

     mysqli_close($dbconn); ?>
```

the problem is that even if it registers, when the hub_code is non existent, it echoes "codexist" meaning that the hub_code already exists.

Comment: Your first condition isn't doing what you think it is but I suppose it sort of works, just a strange way of doing it.  You're doing empty on a condition that all of those variables are not false.  So the result would be true or false for empty to evaluate, so the empty is unnecessary.

Comment: the first condition is supposed to check if any or all the fields in the android activity is empty or not. that works perfectly. its the second and third condition that seems problematic.

Comment: The empty() is completely unnecessary in that first statement. Look at the parenthesis and how it matches up.  You aren't running empty on each one, you are running empty on another condition.

Comment: To clear up this question.  The insert statement does or doesn't run ?

Comment: it runs when the hub_code doesn't exist. it doesn't when the hub_code is same. The latter is what i want. The problem is, it echoes "codexit" even when the insert statement works.

Comment: Judging by your code, the former is what you want.  Correct me if I'm wrong.  I don't see any reason codexit should be echoed when the insert statement is run.   Is this your exact code?  What debugging have you tried?

Comment: it does what its suppsoed to.  when the hub_code is new, it registers but still gives the error as the console receives "codexit" from the php script. 
it  also gives error when the hub_code is existent and it doesn't register which is favorable. tried trial and error.

Comment: let me clear it up one last time. The code is supposed to register the user if the hub_code which the user used to register is different. The code does as its supposed to however when it registers a new user (with a new hub_code that doesn't yet exist) it still gives error because it echoes "codeexit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run your mysql query on your mysql server (not within php) to check that it's behaving as it should.
2. Echo the mysqli_num_rows($result) line. That should help as well, to determine what count is returning.

   3. Echo your $_POST to check that it has been posted correctly.

Trial and error is the only way to debug this.